# How do I graph my equation in R

Tags: r, plot, equation

I have the following equation that I would like to graphy for `y` values between 0 - 20. However I am not sure how to set the data up to use the function `plot (x,y)`.

I first defined my `y` values as:

```
y <- data.frame(x = c(1:20))
```

And then my `x` values as:

```
x<- (exp (-1.973 + 0.598*y) )/ (1+ exp (-1.973+ 0.598*y))
```

I get back this error when using `plot(x,y)`

> Erreur dans stripchart.default(x1, ...) : méthode graphique incorrecte
>   (error in stripchart: method graphic incorrect)

any tips?

Comment: Sorry I meant: y <- data.frame(x = c(1:20))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a data.frame object with y and x value, and afterwards plot it.

```
y <- c(1:20)
x <- exp (-1.973 + 0.598*y) / 1+ exp (-1.973+ 0.598*y)
df <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)
plot(df$y, df$x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw the equation `exp(-1.973+0.598*x)/(1+exp(-1.973+0.598*x))` on the range [0,20], the simplest is to use function `curve`, this way you don't have to define a y or an x vector since it takes an expression directly:

```
curve(exp(-1.973+0.598*x)/(1+exp(-1.973+0.598*x)),from=0,to=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both `x` and `y` are data frames, you have to extract the first column with `[[` before plotting.

```
plot(x[[1]], y[[1]])
```